# Mesh not moving with Armature in pose mode

Tags: armature, pose-mode

I am totally stomped on this one. I have looked into other questions of people having  a similar problem.

1. I have "manipulate center points" turned off
2. It is deformed with Automatic weights. (**See last image**)
3. I made sure all of the vertex groups were deleted before putting on
    the armature
4. Made sure all of the modifiers on the model were applied
5. Made sure that the Armature was on the top of the Modifier stack
6. Made sure that my mesh has nothing locked in the Rotation/Location/Scale
7. Applied the Rotation/Location/Scale of the model
8. I have also tried to use Envelope weights instead of automatic and it gives me a weird result. **See the first image**. It deforms to the mesh but part of the mesh does not move

If any further information is needed to answer this question please let me know and I will update.

Please help
Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first image, those vertices aren't weighted to any bone, you'll have to select the corresponding bones and weight paint them, and in the last image:
1 Put the main mesh in object mode
2 Select all the bones in pose mode, hold shift and click the main mesh, then click back on the bones while still holding shift
3 parent with automatic weights
4 reapply weights on the parts that don't deform as intended

Comment: The first image has envelope weights . As for the last image, automatic weights and those were the results. The method you had described for the envelope weights had no effect unfortunately